# Update values sqlite database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

i've a sqlite database with two columns with values like 4356982 and i want to modify all of this with 43.56982 
there is an sqlite command to make this easy and quick?
i've thought UPDATE command like

```
UPDATE table SET col1,col2
```

but in the conditions?????

Comment: yes but i want to change all values like 4356982 or 42332211 in 43.56982 and 42.332211

Comment: Are they stored as string or integer?

Comment: how about `UPDATE tableName SET col1 = col1 / 100000` and change the datatype to accept decimals.

Comment: please provide column name and types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE MyTable SET col1 = col1 / 100000.0, col2 = col2 / 1000000.0
```

(Take care to use the correct scaling factor.)

Comment: this is command : 
update orari set lat=lat/1000000, long=long/1000000;
this is my error:
Error: columns linea, lat, long, ora, minuti are not unique

Comment: You must use `1000000.0`, otherwise the result is an integer.